# How can I keep the imported data frame in Spyder after closed the session

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to Spyder. And one of my data frame is very big. May I know how I can keep and save the session imported files even if I close Spyder so that when I open again next time I don’t need to reload all data?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Before closing Spyder, you need to save your current variables to a `spydata` file, as described in [our docs](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/variableexplorer.html#toolbar-buttons).

Then, after starting Spyder again, you need to click the `Load` button in the Variable explorer (the one with the arrow pointing downwards) to restore your variables and keep working as usual.